# Which parts of the ImgurV3 API can be used anonymously?

Tags: angularjs, imgur, postman

The documentation says:

> For public read-only and anonymous resources, such as getting image info, looking up user comments, etc. all you need to do is send an authorization header with your client_id in your requests. This also works if you'd like to upload images anonymously (without the image being tied to an account), or if you'd like to create an anonymous album. This lets us know which application is accessing the API.

But it's not clear what the "etc." part includes. It's not clearly defined in the documentation. I have been using Postman to debug before putting this down in AngularJS -- this is just an AngularJS learning project for me -- and I can't get things like the [gallery images for a particular subreddit](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/gallery#subreddit). I get a status 403 back.

Anyone ever done this before?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, if you register for an API key it doesn't take effect right away. The API key you get may not work for a few hours. (I'm guessing this is worst-case.)

It works now, with the exact same code and no changes.